# PHP extract values from array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to extract values from an array within an array. The code I have so far looks like this:

```
$values = $request->request->get('form');
$statusArray = array();
foreach ($values->status as $state) {
    array_push($statusArray, $state);
}
```

The result of doing a var_dump on the $values field is this:

```
array (size=2)   
   'status' => 
      array (size=2)
        0 => string 'New' (length=9)  
        1 => string 'Old' (length=9)    
   'apply' => string '' (length=0)
```

When running the above I get an error basically saying 'status' isn't an object. Can anyone tell me how I can extract the values of the array within 'status'??

Comment: a `var_dump($values);` would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->` it's the notation to access object values, for arrays you have to use `['key']`:

```
foreach ($values['status'] as $state) {
  array_push($statusArray, $state);
}
```

Object example:

```
class Foo {
  $bar = 'Bar';
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->bar // prints "bar"
```

Comment: So what's wrong with using `->`? His `get('form')` function can still return an object, and he can use it in his loop: `foreach ($values->status as $state)`

Comment: Actually if you see the `var_dump` it says that `get('form')`returns an array, if it would have returned an object you could have used the `->` notation like you suggested otherwise this kind of notation is not defined for arrays and you will incur in exceptions.

Comment: That's true. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: If you don't know what kind of variable you are getting back, you can use `is_array` or `is_object` to determine which kind of access operator to use.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Is it possible to do a null check on the array? For example, status may not always exist within the array. I tried to do something like this: 'if ($values['status'] != null){'  but just get a Undefined index: status error

Comment: You can use `isset`, `if(isset($values['status']))` which returns true if the key exists, false otherwise.